# Function condition on panel data with rollmean function - zoo package R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, zoo, moving-average

On a rollmean function (zoo package),

```
SP_stock$mean_vol_260<-ave(as.numeric(SP_stock$vol), SP_stock$ID, FUN=function(x) rollmean(x,k=260, na.pad=T, align="right"))
```

I have an error that says :

```
 Error : k <= n is not TRUE
```

because for some of my IDs I don't have enough values (260).

I'd like to put a condition to do the rollmean function only on IDs that has at least 260 values on $vol.

And if its possible, to do the rollmean function on as much value as possible, up to 260 for the other one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `k = min(NROW(x), 260)`?

Comment: `function(x) rollapplyr(x, 260, mean, partial = TRUE)` can be used to set the m-th componeht of the result to `mean(x[1:m])` for m < 260.  This is not exactly what you asked for but it might be useful anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set `k = min(NROW(x), 260)`:

```
SP_stock$mean_vol_260 <- ave(as.numeric(SP_stock$vol), SP_stock$ID,
  FUN=function(x) rollmeanr(x, k=min(NROW(x), 260), na.pad=TRUE))
```